# Well practices contributing to Sylius

Tags: git, github, sylius

I'm very new at git and I would like to contribute to Sylius project via GitHub. And I wonder what would be the best practices to do that.

I have make a fork of the main repository and I would like to modify it to suit my needs but I would like to contribute also with some bugfixes and so.

This is my workflow at the moment:

1. Fork the project
2. Clone in local
   Here comes the doubts:
3. Create new branch "myproject" (which contains modifications for my project)
4. Install: a) "composer update" b)"app/console sylius:install"
5. Create a topic branch (bug fix, new feature..)
6. Pull Request of topic branch

And, If I want to pull new updates of the master branch:

1. pull from main project into master
2. merge master into myproject

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last part is wrong, it should be rebase, Sylius already has some documentation that was merged days ago on that. It is the same almost as the symfony one. In my opinion if you are also starting or want to heavily contribute to any project check Gush. http://github.com/gushphp/gush you will never regret it and I offer 100% support to its usage :)

This question of yours is particularly focused on Sylius, I think i talked about rebasing on the earlier versions of the book you have. I personally rebase even my own projects but i try to keep the customization to a minimum of commits so that i can rebase them well and quickly to upgrade to several versions later.

Other than that just check Sylius documentation on contributions.